# Сложность алогритма

Tags: c++

Не свосем понимаю, как оценить сложность алгоритма ниже. По самой наивной логике, можно сказать, что есть 5 циклов. Первый выполняется N раз, остальные 4 вложенные, значит, сложность N^4. Но это, конечно, не так. Измерение времени мне не дало таких результатов. Как провести правильную оценку?

```
int LEN = S.size(); 

  
   std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> P(LEN, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(LEN, std::vector<double>(LEN, 0.0)));

   for(int i{0}; i < LEN; i++) P[i][i][0] = S[i] - '0';                 

   for(int run{2}; run <= LEN; run++) {                                  
      for(int i{0}, j = i + run - 1; i <= LEN - run; i++, j++) {          
         P[i][j][0] = 10 * P[i][j-1][0] + P[j][j][0];                    
         for(int deg{1}; deg < run; deg++) {                              
            P[i][j][deg] = P[i][i][0] + X * P[i+1][j][deg-1];            
            for(int c = i + 1; c < j - deg + 1; c++) P[i][j][deg] = std::min(P[i][j][deg], P[i][c][0] + X * P[c+1][j][deg-1]);
         }
      }
   }
   return *std::min_element(P[0][LEN-1].begin(), P[0][LEN-1].begin()+LEN);
```

Comment: Не стоит смешивать в одну кашу алгоритмическую асимптотику и время выполнения. Ну и код надо приводить настоящий.

Comment: @user7860670 дополнил код

Comment: Это учебное задание? Тогда приведите ваши попытки оценить сложность. Слов "четыре цикла" недостаточно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, недостаточно. Но это все мои рассуждения на данный момент. Поэтому и написал, что "наивно"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отформатированный и размеченный код:

```
/*  1 */ int LEN = S.size(); 
/*  2 */ std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> P(LEN,
/*  3 */     std::vector<std::vector<double>>(LEN,
/*  4 */         std::vector<double>(LEN, 0.0)
/*    */     )
/*    */ );
/*    */ 
/*  5 */ for(int i{0}; i < LEN; i++)
/*  6 */     P[i][i][0] = S[i] - '0';                 
/*    */ 
/*  7 */ for (int run{2}; run <= LEN; run++) {                                  
/*  8 */     for (int i{0}, j = i + run - 1; i <= LEN - run; i++, j++) {          
/*  9 */         P[i][j][0] = 10 * P[i][j-1][0] + P[j][j][0];                    
/* 10 */         for (int deg{1}; deg < run; deg++) {                              
/* 11 */             P[i][j][deg] = P[i][i][0] + X * P[i+1][j][deg-1];            
/* 12 */             for (int c = i + 1; c < j - deg + 1; c++)
/* 13 */                 P[i][j][deg] = std::min(P[i][j][deg], P[i][c][0] + X * P[c+1][j][deg-1]);
/*    */         }
/*    */     }
/*    */ }
/* 14 */ return *std::min_element(P[0][LEN-1].begin(), P[0][LEN-1].begin()+LEN);
```

Конструирование вектора через `vector(N, V)` требует сделать `N` копий значения `V`. Время одного копирования пропорционально размеру `V`. Полное время конструирования `N * size(V)`. Самый внутренний вектор конструируется за `LEN`:

```
/*  2        */ std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> P(LEN,
/*  3        */     std::vector<std::vector<double>>(LEN,
/*  4 T: LEN */         std::vector<double>(LEN, 0.0)
/*           */     )
/*           */ );
```

Вектор на уровень выше конструируется за `LEN * size(V) == LEN^2`. На самом верхнем уровне аналогично:

```
/*  2 T: LEN^3 */ std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> P(LEN,
/*  3 T: LEN^2 */     std::vector<std::vector<double>>(LEN,
/*  4 T: LEN   */         std::vector<double>(LEN, 0.0)
/*             */     )
/*             */ );
```

Когда кусок кода оценен полностью, сам код стираем, сложности в строках складываем:

```
/*  2-4 T: LEN^3 + LEN^2 + LEN */
```

Выражения упрощаем по правилам О-большого:

```
/*  2-4 T: LEN^3 */
```

Следующий кусок:

```
/*  5 */ for(int i{0}; i < LEN; i++)
/*  6 */     P[i][i][0] = S[i] - '0';
```

Арифметика вычисляется за константу. Заголовок цикла `for` тратит константу на каждую итерацию (не пишем) и повторяется `LEN` раз:

```
/*  5 F: LEN */ for(int i{0}; i < LEN; i++)
/*  6 T: 1   */     P[i][i][0] = S[i] - '0';
```

Так как сложность тела цикла не меняется, то достаточно умножить число повторений на сложность тела:

```
/*  5-6 T: LEN */
```

Следующий цикл разбираем изнутри наружу:

```
/* 12 */ for (int c = i + 1; c < j - deg + 1; c++)
/* 13 */     P[i][j][deg] = std::min(P[i][j][deg], P[i][c][0] + X * P[c+1][j][deg-1]);
```

Число повторений цикла понятно как записать. Тело цикла имеет постоянную сложность:

```
/* 12 F: (j - deg + 1) - (i + 1) */ for (int c = i + 1; c < j - deg + 1; c++)
/* 13 T: 1                       */     P[i][j][deg] = std::min(P[i][j][deg], P[i][c][0] + X * P[c+1][j][deg-1]);
```

Итог:

```
/* 12-13 T: j - i - deg */
```

На уровень выше:

```
/* 10                   */ for (int deg{1}; deg < run; deg++) {                              
/* 11                   */     P[i][j][deg] = P[i][i][0] + X * P[i+1][j][deg-1];            
/* 12-13 T: j - i - deg */
/*                      */ }
```

Складываем сложности в теле, считаем итерации:

```
/* 10    F: run - 1         */ for (int deg{1}; deg < run; deg++) {                              
/* 11-13 T: 1 + j - i - deg */
/*                          */ }
```

Итог:

```
/* 10-13 T: (run - 1) * (1 + j - i - deg) */
```

Ещё на уровень выше:

```
/*  8                                     */ for (int i{0}, j = i + run - 1; i <= LEN - run; i++, j++) {          
/*  9                                     */     P[i][j][0] = 10 * P[i][j-1][0] + P[j][j][0];                    
/* 10-13 T: (run - 1) * (1 + j - i - deg) */
/*                                        */ }


/*  8    F: (LEN - run) - 0 + 1           */ for (int i{0}, j = i + run - 1; i <= LEN - run; i++, j++) {          
/*  9    T: 1                             */     P[i][j][0] = 10 * P[i][j-1][0] + P[j][j][0];                    
/* 10-13 T: (run - 1) * (1 + j - i - deg) */
/*                                        */ }


/* 8    F: (LEN - run) + 1                   */ for (int i{0}, j = i + run - 1; i <= LEN - run; i++, j++) {          
/* 9-13 T: 1 + (run - 1) * (1 + j - i - deg) */
/*                                           */ }
```

По заголовку цикла можно вычислить `j - i`: значение не меняется и равно `run - 1`. Подставим его:

```
/* 8    F: (LEN - run) + 1             */ for (int i{0}, j = i + run - 1; i <= LEN - run; i++, j++) {          
/* 9-13 T: 1 + (run - 1) * (run - deg) */
/*                                     */ }
```

Итог:

```
/* 8-13 T: (LEN - run + 1) * (1 + (run - 1) * (run - deg)) */
```

Верхний уровень цикла:

```
/* 7    F: LEN - run - 1                                   */ for (int run{2}; run <= LEN; run++) {                                  
/* 8-13 T: (LEN - run + 1) * (1 + (run - 1) * (run - deg)) */
/*                                                         */ }
```

Оцениваем множители сверху: `LEN - run + 1 <= LEN`, `run - 1 <= LEN`, `run - deg <= LEN`. Правила О-большого:

```
/* 7    F: LEN             */ for (int run{2}; run <= LEN; run++) {                                  
/* 8-13 T: LEN * LEN * LEN */
/*                         */ }
```

Итог:

```
/* 7-13 T: LEN^4 */
```

Последний оператор:

```
/* 14 */ return *std::min_element(P[0][LEN-1].begin(), P[0][LEN-1].begin()+LEN);
```

Он работает за линейное время от числа элементов (`LEN`):

```
/* 14 T: LEN */
```

Всё вместе:

```
/* 1    T: 1     */ int LEN = S.size(); 
/* 2-4  T: LEN^3 */
/* 5-6  T: LEN   */
/* 7-13 T: LEN^4 */
/* 14   T: LEN   */
```

Складываем, применяем О-большое:

```
/* 1-14 T: LEN^4 */
```